# Android slide over letters to create a word

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gesture

I am searching for a library or an algorithm to achieve the following functionality in Android:

[image]

I want to show letters on the screen; the user can select the letters by swiping over them to create a word.

I know this isn't really a programming question, but its related to programming and Android.

Comment: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I assume you know programming android is based on java, so building algorithm I can help with some a primitive algorithm solution for you, but you need to implement the UI and the java code in your Android App, as if I also should do that it will be full project, and that is not the idea, let me know if I should processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some advice you can use:

First for each cell you can create an object that represents the state of that cell:

```
class Cell {
   char mChar;
   int row,column;
   boolean isSelected;
}
```

then you can create a 2D array of your cells

```
Cell[][] mTable = ...
```

For views you have a lot of options:

for cells:

- [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)
- [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)
- [CheckableImageView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/photup/blob/master/client/src/uk/co/senab/photup/views/CheckableImageView.java) ( I think this one is more suitable)
- [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

and for the viewgroup for your entire table you can choose any of the below:

- [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)
- [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)
- [RelativaLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)
- Nested [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)(not recommended)
- [Custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) ( you can create a `viewgroup` for your specific needs)

For detecting swipe gesture set [OnSwipeTouchListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)(from which answers you like) as a `TouchListener` of your cell views. This listener gives callbacks on these events:

- onSwipeRight()
- onSwipeLeft()
- onSwipeTop()
- onSwipeBottom()

---

Game Architecture

You can use MVC architecture for this one. You need another class call it `GameController`. When you detect a swipe
you have to pass it to the `GameController` with the index of that cell. `GameController` has to check if that swipe is valid or not for example diagonal swipe may not valid or... the rules are applied here. Then if the swipe is valid `GameController` updates the `mTable`(set `isSelected` to `true` for example) and then you have to update your `ui` from `mTable` data.

I think the whole idea is now a bit clearer to you, look forward to playing it :-)